# Creating a case with PHP Toolkit 20.0 fails

Tags: php, enterprise, ajax-toolkit

I'm trying to create a case with PHP Toolkit 20.0 (Enterprise) and I can't get it to work.

**PHP:**

```
$sObject = new stdclass();
$sObject->ZCN_number__c = $_SESSION['zcn'];
$sObject->ContactId = $_SESSION['contact_id'];
$sObject->AccountId = $_SESSION['account_id'];
$sObject->OwnerId = $ownerId;
$sObject->Status = 'New';
$sObject->Priority = 'Medium';
$sObject->Origin = 'Web';
$sObject->Subject = $_POST['subject'];
$sObject->Description = $_POST['description'];

try {

  $createResponse = $mySforceConnection->create(array($sObject), 'Case');

  $ids = array();
  foreach ($createResponse as $createResult) {
    print_r($createResult);
    array_push($ids, $createResult->id);
  }

  //header("Location: response.php");
  exit;
}
catch (Exception $e){

  echo $mySforceConnection->getLastRequest();
  echo $e->faultstring;
  exit;

}
```

**Error message:**

> Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: .stdClass
>   Object
>       (
>           [errors] => Array
>               (
>                   [0] => stdClass Object
>                       (
>                           [message] => The record couldn’t be saved because it failed to trigger a flow. 
> A flow trigger failed to
>   execute the flow with version ID 301b0000000PE86. 
>  Contact your
>   administrator for help.
>                           [statusCode] => CANNOT_EXECUTE_FLOW_TRIGGER    )
>        )  [id] =>   [success] =>   )

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please have a look at the following known issue: https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p30000000T3sCAAS

Could this be the issue you're experiencing?